# Display youtube videos thumbnail and title inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api

I am attempting to display the results of my prefetched YouTube search. My search function prints out the title, thumbnails and video ID. I would like to assign the title and thumbnails inside of my table cell. The goal is to eventually play the video when the cell for that video is clicked. But for now I would like to just display the relevant information for the index of that table cell.

```
    func search() {
    let videoType = "motivation"

    var dataArray = [[String: AnyObject]]()

    var apiKey = "xxxxx"
    var urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=\(videoType)&type=video&videoSyndicated=true&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=10&safeSearch=strict&order=relevance&order=viewCount&type=video&relevanceLanguage=en&regionCode=GB&key=\(apiKey)"

    urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
    let targetURL = URL(string: urlString)

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default // Session Configuration
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: targetURL!) {

        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)

            return
        }

        else {
            do {
                typealias JSONObject = [String:AnyObject]

                let  json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! JSONObject
                let items  = json["items"] as! Array<JSONObject>
                for i in 0 ..< items.count {

                    let snippetDictionary = items[i]["snippet"] as! JSONObject
                    print(snippetDictionary)
                    var youVideoDict = JSONObject()

                    youVideoDict["title"] = snippetDictionary["title"]
                    youVideoDict["channelTitle"] = snippetDictionary["channelTitle"]
                    youVideoDict["thumbnail"] = ((snippetDictionary["thumbnails"] as! JSONObject)["high"] as! JSONObject)["url"]
                    youVideoDict["videoID"] = (items[i]["id"] as! JSONObject)["videoId"]
                    dataArray.append(youVideoDict)

                    print(dataArray)
                }
            }

            catch {
                print("json error: \(error)")
            }

        }
    }
    task.resume() 
}

     override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    search()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(YouTubeTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    view.addSubview(containerView)
    view.addSubview(titleLabel)
    containerView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 200, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 200, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)

    containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    containerView.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    tableView.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: containerView.leftAnchor, bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor, right: containerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    titleLabel.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: containerView.topAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 10, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 140
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! YouTubeTableCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = "youtube video title"
    cell.thumbnail.image = 
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

1-

```
 dataArray.append(youVideoDict) 
 print(dataArray)
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

2-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataArray.count
}
```

3-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! YouTubeTableCell
    let item = dataArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = item["title"] as! String
    let url = item["thumbnail"] as! String
    cell.thumbnail.sd_setImage(with:url), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")) 
    return cell
}
```

and install [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

> Tip: it's better to use `Codable` to decode the reponse to model instead of `JSONSerialization` and `Dictionary`

Comment: thank you for the response. This keeps returning an empty tableView. In fact my tableView heightForRowAt won't even work. Might you know what the issue is?

Comment: set the delegate ans datasource ?

Comment: yes in viewDidLoad() set both self.tableView.delegate = self and same with self.tableView.datasource
.

Comment: get `print("json error: \(error)")`  ? call `search` from `viewDidLoad` ??

Comment: i think the problem is on retuning dataArray.count beause when I set it to return 3 rows the height and the dummy text show up again.